# SVG Rectangle width animation not working in Firefox

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I've been trying to animate the width of an svg rectangle using css, and it seems to be working with chrome and opera, but isn't working in firefox, I'd appreciate any help in this, thanks in advance

https://codepen.io/goprime/pen/BOPBjM

And here's the code:

HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
                    <!-- Generator: Gravit.io --><svg class="responsive-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="908.444 448 948 1114"
                        width="948" height="1114">

                        <!-- This is the main background -->
                        <g>
                            <rect x="908.444" y="448" width="948" height="1114" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" fill="white" />
                            <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1232.227,773.652)">

                                <text transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,76.957)" style="font-family:'Source Sans Pro';font-weight:400;font-size:72px;font-style:normal;fill:#A4A598;stroke:none;">INTERIOR</text></g>

                           </g>

                            <!-- First box cover-->
                            <rect class="anim_test_top" x="1130" y="773.652" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) rotate(180 1430 820.652)"
                                fill="white" />

 </svg>
```

CSS:

```
.anim_test_top {
  /* stroke:cyan; */
  width: 530px;
  height: 80px;
  animation: anim 2s linear forwards;
}



@keyframes anim {
  from {
    width: 630.214px;
  }

  to {
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: conver to SMIL. In Firefox width/height of rect elements are not CSS properties.

Comment: @RobertLongson Hi, thank you for the reply, I just had one more question, is it okay if I leave the current code as it is, and add the SMIL part just for firefox? Is there a way for me to specify the smil code to work only in firefox?

Comment: it's your code, do what you like. Chrome/Opera support SMIL though.

Comment: @RobertLongson got it, thank you so much for the help, I just have one more small question, so I've created the animation with SMIL, but one the animation is complete, it reverts back to its original state, is there a way for it to stay the way it is at the end of animation?

Comment: add fill="freeze"

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much, you just saved me from hours more of stress! Have a great day

Comment: Be aware that if you have both a CSS animation **and** an SMIL one, then they can compete with each other and you maye get strange effects due to the combination.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Yeah I was a bit late in seeing your warning haha, but yeah, I did get a lot of strange effects, so I'm trying to use anime.js instead of SMIL or CSS

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to translate the `#anim_test_top`? Next come my code where I'm translating the `#anim_test_top`. Also I've made some changes to your SVG since you have too may transforms.

```css
svg{max-height:100vh;}
#anim_test_top {
  stroke:cyan;
  width: 450px;
  height: 100px;
  transform:translate(0, 0);
  animation: anim 2s linear forwards;
}

text{font-family:'Source Sans Pro';font-weight:400;font-size:72px;font-style:normal;fill:#A4A598;stroke:none;}


@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform:translate(0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform:translate(450px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="responsive-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 948 500">

<!-- This is the main background -->
<g>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="948" height="1114" fill="#eee" />
<g>
<text y="200" x="424" id="text"  text-anchor="middle">INTERIOR</text></g>
</g>
<!-- First box cover-->
<rect id="anim_test_top" width="450" height="100" x="200" y="130" fill="rgba(255,255,255,.75)" >
</rect>
</svg>
```

I hope this helps

UPDATE:

if translating is out of question you can scale the rectangle:

```css
svg{max-height:100vh;}
#anim_test_top {
  stroke:cyan;
  width: 450px;
  height: 100px;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform:scale(1, 1);
  animation: anim 2s linear forwards;
}

text{font-family:'Source Sans Pro';font-weight:400;font-size:72px;font-style:normal;fill:#A4A598;stroke:none;}


@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform:scale(1, 1);
  }

  100% {
    transform:scale(0, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="responsive-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 948 500">

<!-- This is the main background -->
<g>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="948" height="1114" fill="#eee" />
<g>
<text y="200" x="424" id="text"  text-anchor="middle">INTERIOR</text></g>
</g>
<!-- First box cover-->
<rect id="anim_test_top" width="450" height="100" x="200" y="130" fill="rgba(255,255,255,.75)" >
</rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying, and that's a great idea, unfortunately I can't use translate, as the box will be out of bounds, thus creating some visual disturbance

Comment: If translating is out of question you can scale the rectangle. I've updated my answer. Please take a look.